# Highcharts Stock Chart Date Not Appearing Properly

Tags: javascript, python, highcharts

I'm following the sample Highcharts Stock example with the data format [date, price]

My chart is loading but I'm having issues with the date part of the chart. Here's a view of what chart looks like:
[image]

I'm getting the data from the Yahoo Finance API. Here's what the data looks like I'm loading to the chart.

```
0: (2) ['1493596800000', 68.202003479]
1: (2) ['1496275200000', 72.3219985962]
2: (2) ['1498867200000', 64.6940002441]
3: (2) ['1501545600000', 71.1800003052]
4: (2) ['1504224000000', 68.2200012207]
5: (2) ['1506816000000', 66.3059997559]
6: (2) ['1509494400000', 61.7700004578]
7: (2) ['1512086400000', 62.2700004578]
```

The only difference I can see is that the date in my data has single quotes around it whereas, in the sample data, there are no quotes.

Would removing those quotes somehow do the trick?

That's another issue, I'm not sure how to do this in JS. I've tried wrapping my date data in JS with moment() but the same problem.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Ok i think i figured it out and probably should have known this..but using parseInt on the date string worked perfectly

Comment: Great, the format should be parse to `[1623677400000,130.48],[1623763800000,129.64],[1623850200000,130.15]`